# Is possible to connect the company DB to Odoo 9 (OpenERP)?

Tags: database, postgresql, odoo, erp

I am creating a business app to manage the inventory of a mid-sized shoe company. 
I already have a database created with PostgreSQL. I would now be able to connect it to Odoo 9 to develop applications.

How can I do that?

Comment: previously you was using Odoo8/7/6 or another erp

Comment: @PrakashSharma I think he used a database for an external app. If you want to use the same database, take care of the name of you table in this database, because if Odoo needs to create the same table, you will have a table with mix data from Odoo and from you application. But, just run Odoo with "-d your_database" when you run the Odoo app.

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET The company has always used the IBM AS/400 system where the database is integrated with the OS. Now there are new needs and gradually the company want to create a new Web-based system. I started building a new database model, I implemented it using PostgreSQL (since it's supported by Odoo). But now I want to build business applications using my database. Odoo 9 seemed to me a good choice. What do you think?

Comment: @QuentinTHEURET I never used Odoo, but from what I understand, it would seem that Odoo builds its tables and doesn't use existing ones. Is this true? What is the best practice in such cases? Note that I want to use my DB model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just use your existing data directly with odoo

But Odoo makes it easy to use existing data from existing applications and databases with it's flexible import system. in which data is imported to it via csv files, you can import any data you can possibly think of, you just have to know the right format of data that odoo is expecting and the required fields you have to provide

Every model in Odoo even custom built modules can have data imported into them

If you want to import data just click on the listview of any model and you should see an `import` link beside the `create` button, from there you can carry on, there's even a FAQ there which you can read if you need to find out more about the import system.

As for knowing the required columns that have to be present when you're importing, Just create sample data and save it, Then

- Go to the listview
- Tick the check-box beside the record name to select it
- Now click on the more button you should see an export option
- From there you can pick the fields you want to export, the required fields will highlighted in blue

There are other ways of re-using existing data with odoo (You can write to the database directly...but this is not recommended as several constraints would not be checked and you can end up messing the database up) or you can use `xmlrpc` or `jsonrpc` which is going to be time consuming

Using the import functionality is the best and the easiest way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm considering to build a web app using a backend framework (e.g. Django). Do you think that Odoo can be a good ERP for a mid-sized company?

Comment: Yes I'll definitely recommend odoo....but you should also know that odoo has an inbuilt web framework which can be used to build web apps that integrate tightly with odoo. and also avoid the complexity of using another framework...(it's very similar to flask because it uses werkzeug and you can also use jinja2 if you want)